# How can I add $@user:$ in the comment box?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment error while posting comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/comment-error-while-posting-comments)

I put my comment in the comment box beginning with "@user:". But finally the context remain without "@user:". This situation happened several times.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just came up in a [recent meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/are-users-here-not-dear). There is a new policy of [stripping @user salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation) from posts if there are no other users in the comment thread other than the post owner.

Comment: [Chandru's question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/comment-error-while-posting-comments) seems to be a better match.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't remembered that one. I've closed this question as a duplicate now.