# Are the words "hey guys" blacklisted and automatically stripped from edits?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, blacklist

Today I chose to edit a post that I found in the "First questions" queue. It began with the words "Hey guys", and I chose to leave them since they expressed the OP's personality and style, even if I don't really like them. To my surprise, saving my edit removed these words from the post. I tried to edit it again several times in order to add them back, but each time the saved text did not contain them. What should I make out of this? Does the MSE software filter these words out automatically? If so, why didn't it remove them from the original version of the post, as well?

I won't link to the post because I do not want to artificially increase its view count, but its [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4255388/revisions) should be enough for the curious.

Comment: I tried that post and same for me. I wonder why it is there in the first place...

Comment: I have looked at the older post: [Are users here not dear?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2513) It leads to this answer on [meta.se], which contains a regex used for these purposes: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950#93989)

Comment: I guess this means the regex is used for edits, but doesn't it say that they are removed from posts at time of posting? (precise wording: "We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.")

Comment: Just as a matter of record:  salutations and sign offs (e.g. "Thanks!") are considered noise, and you should remove such phrases when you are making other edits.  Don't edit a post just to remove this noise, but if you are already in there to do other stuff, "Hey guys" should be taken out.

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is interesting - I did not look that closely into the revision history and I have missed this distinction. I assumed that the filter for salutation works the same way when a question (or an answer) is posted and when it is edited. Based on this example, it seems that I was wrong.

Comment: @XanderHenderson this may be kind of a dumb question, but what's wrong with noise?

Comment: @Jackson The underlying philosophy of the SE model is that this is a Question and Answer site.  It is not a social media site.  The goal is to create a repository of questions with high quality answers, in a somewhat encyclopedic style.  This is about *content*, not interaction.

Comment: As far as direct impact to those goals, does noise lower the quantity or quality of questions or answers?

Comment: I enjoy occasionally stamping on my personality on an answer, such as via "$\epsilon$ and $\delta$ say hello, if I am going to be presenting an approach that uses $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  I can get away with it, because it isn't *all noise*, since it sends an informative message to the reader.  I avoid doing that with questions however, because mathSE questions are very highly scrutinized, so I strive to a purist approach for questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Does the MSE software filter these words out automatically?

Yes. According to [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), "*hey*" and"*guys*" will be removed automatically, **only if it's on the start of body (including whitespace)**.

> If so, why didn't it remove them from the original version of the post, as well?

What happened with [the original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/9218e8ad-4d08-48a4-80a5-00dcb9c8740f/view-source) was that **it started with "\" (backslash)**, which is not the character included in the regex pattern.

For posterity:

```
\
Hey guys,\
```

Comment: excellent; I should have of course read the regex! :)

Comment: @AndrewT.: Just curious: given that you are not really active on MSE (and even less so on Meta.MSE), how did you find out about this question?

Comment: @AlexM. just a coincidence while randomly browsing meta sites :)

Comment: For me: hot network questions. I guess "hot" is a matter of debate 

Comment: One of the dumbest things I've seen.